# How do I configure phoenix /elixir apps to accept https requests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have created some phoenix apps and all seem to by default not accept https requests. I get the error `[error] Cowboy returned 400 and there are no headers in the connection.`. Http requests return data as expected.

Comment: I would't do this. I would rather serve only http requests with Phoenix and let some http server like Nginx to serve both http and https requests. Nginx will proxy them to Phoenix. Easy to setup and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to configure your app's endpoint in the relevant `config.exs` - something like:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: System.get_env("HOST"), port: 443],
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]]
```

where `System.get_env("HOST")` is your app's url... `localhost:4000`, in the case of local development, I'd think.

Documentation - http://wsmoak.net/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html

Then you'll need to add the CORS plug - https://github.com/mschae/cors_plug

I built a Phoenix app to act as an API, and I followed the doc's instructions, setting it up in my router like they did, more or less:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug CORSPlug, [origin: Application.get_env(:my_app, :client_url)]
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
end


scope "/api", PhoenixApp do
  pipe_through :api

  resources "/articles", ArticleController
  options   "/articles", ArticleController, :options
  options   "/articles/:id", ArticleController, :options
end
```

Comment: Better to use `url: [scheme: "https", host: {:system, "HOST"}, port: 443],` instead of  `url: [scheme: "https", host: System.get_env("HOST"), port: 443],`. The second variation will fix your configuration to **build time environment variable** `HOST`. `{:system, "HOST"}` evaluates at runtime.